# How to write one-line logs with tinylog 2?

Tags: java, logging, tinylog

I'm using https://tinylog.org/v2/ for logging.

Per default the framework logs each statement in two lines

```
2020-10-25 20:07:27 [main] org.reflections.Reflections.scan()
INFO: Reflections took 288 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 5 keys and 22 values
```

How can I avoid this behaviour? The preferred solution would be programmatic one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a format pattern for your log entries via the [Configuration class](https://tinylog.org/v2/javadoc/org/tinylog/configuration/Configuration.html) programmatically.

Example:

```
Configuration.set("writer", "console");
Configuration.set("writer.format", "{date} [{thread}] {class}.{method}() {level}: {message}");
```